# Use thumbnail image using url of that image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have the URL of my image and I want to display the thumbnail of that image. Is this possible. I check `the_post_thumbnail()` function but I can't add the URL of the image as an input.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing in more detail. How is it that you know the URL but can't get the ID?

Comment: I'm using redux framework. I add an image with that and to diplay that image i use the url. like this: <img src="<?php echo $test_wp['no_image_post_IMG']['url']; ?>">

Comment: ok got it: <?php echo $test_wp['no_image_post_IMG']['id']; ?> that get the id (i feel stupid)

Comment: What is `var_dump($test_wp['no_image_post_IMG']);`?

Comment: it is the var of redux

Comment: But that doesn't tell me what the ***output*** is! What the variable looks like!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34022/discussion-between-pablo-levin-and-s-ha-dum).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the image ID from the URL with [`attachment_url_to_postid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/):

```
$image_id   = attachment_url_to_postid( $image_url );
```

Convert the ID to the thumbnail image URL with [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/):

```
$thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

Comment: I was just about to test the function using a featured image URL. Did you try this? At any rate, those "url to ID" functions are resource heavy and best avoided if possible.

Comment: You should not post bare code. A good answer contains verbal explanation as well. Not my downvote, but I am pretty sure that is the "why" of the vote.

Comment: Either another user or the system has flagged this as [low quality (*see flag*)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/94736). Please stop dumping code, to be really honest, this is not the first low quality flag I handle on your of your post. I'm really not after you as you have previously claimed, but I cannot overlook low quality flags in review queue. Add proper explanation to your code to avoid your posts being auto-flagged or being flagged by other users

Comment: I'm almost certain that single code blocks, like it was originally, are getting always flagged as low quality. So it is better to do the explanation not as code comment, but as regular text.

Comment: That is an improvement. Links to the Codex page for the relevant functions are always a good thing. caveats are helpful-- "not tested but...", "this might break if..."